# tomcat double decode url

Tags: tomcat, urldecode, utf8-decode

I am using spring security and spring mvc
i want to send in get method  1+1@gmail.com

1.when i typing in the browser localhost:8080/myServlerturl/login?user=1%2B1@gmail.com 
i am getting in the /login 
 request.getParameterMap().get("user") is 1+1

2.when i typing in the browser localhost:8080/myServlerturl/login?user=1+1@gmail.com 
i am getting in the /login 
 request.getParameterMap().get("user") is 1 1

i deduce from this that that the tomcat do double encdoing meaning 
the browser change 1+1 to 1%2B1 (browser always decode url) tomcat change it to 1 1 meaning double encode .

i see in the first filter I have the parameter as 1 1 insead of seeing it as 1+1

(url encode)(2 X decode by tomcat ) = decode X 1 too much

Answer (score 1):

Some characters have to be [percent encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) in URLs, no matter what. This is how HTTP works.

Your 2)nd case doesn't make much sense. If such a URL is generated (without percent encoding `+` sign), it is generated incorrectly and must be fixed.